# Erro HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, web-service

Estou utilizando este código abaixo, para enviar um `xml` para o `webservice` da prefeitura, o máximo de RPS que envia é 40. O que ocorre é que eu já enviei com 40 e não obtive problemas anteriormente.
É gerado apenas uma vez por mês, quando eu gero por exemplo, estou tentando gerar com 13 RPS, ele me retorna um erro genérico:

> An error occurred while sending the request.; The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response.

Então não consigo saber onde está o problema, pensei que poderia ser no código, porém com 1 RPS por lote enviei corretamente, e com 5 também.

```
 private string postB(string url, string method, string xml, string numero, int idempresa, string ws)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

            doc.Load(xml);

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = getWebRequestB(url, method);
            webRequest.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;
            //webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            webRequest.Proxy = HttpWebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
            webRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            webRequest.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();
            Uri myUri = new Uri("http://192.168.0.3:3128");
            myProxy.Address = myUri;
            myProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            webRequest.Proxy = myProxy;


            montaEnvelopeB(webRequest, doc, numero, xml, idempresa, ws);

            return getSoapResponseB(webRequest);
        }
        catch (WebException webex)
        {
            WebResponse errResp = webex.Response;
            if (errResp != null)
            {
                using (Stream respStream = errResp.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStream);

                    msgm = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    cod = "Erro";
                }
            }
            else { cod = "Erro";  msgm = webex.ToString(); }

            return msgm;
        }
    }
```

Já tentei colocar com `webRequest.KeepAlive = true;` porém não deu,e nem colocando com `false`.

Comment: A mensagem informa que a requisição não resultou em um status de sucesso, porém a ela pode estar trazendo uma descrição do erro. Provavelmente se trata de um 400 (Bad request) por você não estar entregando o xml no envelope que o serviço está esperando

Comment: @LeandroAngelo então o xml é gerado da mesma forma, com o mesmo tratamento, quando eu envio vários ele retorna esse erro, quando eu envio menos vai, até pensei que poderia ser algo que não estava tratado, algum caractere em especial ou algo do tipo, mas ao gerar um por um, ou 5 por exemplo, dava certo.

Comment: nesse cenário faz sentido ser algum caractere ou um dos itens que está quebrando o seu lote mesmo